# How can I make a heroku git submodule act "invisible" to a higher git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, express, github, heroku

My express/react structure looks like the following:

```
my-app/           //(git repo 1)
├─ .git/
├─ frontend/
│  ├─ src/
│  ├─ public/
│  ├─ package.json
│  ├─ node_modules/
├─ backend/      //(git repo 2 -> heroku)
│  ├─ .git/
│  ├─ build/
│  ├─ index.js
│  ├─ app.js
│  ├─ controllers/
│  ├─ models/
│  │  ├─ model1.js
│  ├─ package.json
```

Essentially, a simple frontend/backend structure with the `frontend` folder containing a react app, while the `backend` folder contains the express backend along with a separate git remote for heroku deployments. The `my-app` folder also is a git repo which I keep this entire web app project in.

The problem is it seems that the `my-app` (git repo 1) git repo completely ignores any changes that happen in the `backend` folder, which is bad because I need to track the **entire** project with git repo 1. However, I still need to keep git repo 2 active in order to deploy the app to hosting services like Heroku.

When I try to add `backend/models/model1.js` to git repo 1:

```
git add my-app/backend/models/model1.js
```

I get the following error:

`fatal: Pathspec 'my-app/backend/models/model1.js' is in submodule 'my-app/backend'`

So I can see what's going on here: `my-app/backend` is a submodule of `my-app` and my goal is to essentially have the effect `my-app/backend` "invisible" to `my-app`, where `my-app` still tracks all changes **inside** of `my-app/backend`, but I'm still able to deploy the `my-app/backend` folder to Heroku via git push.

Comment: A repository holds commits, and commits hold files. Neither a repository nor a commit *is* a (single) file though, so a commit can't hold a submodule. Instead, a submodule is implemented as a sort of fake file: it's a "file" in each commit that tells the superproject Git "go clone the submodule, if needed, then check out commit <hash> in the other repository". So you literally can't get what you want, with submodules.

Comment: There *is* a thing in Git (`git subtree`) that *can* do what you want, but it's rather neglected and has known bugs that nobody has ever gotten around to fixing, so I don't particularly recommend it. You might be able to get what you want from it, though.

Comment: Your other option is to change what you want, so that it matches what Git and/or Heroku support. That's the way I'd go if I were doing this. (Well, that, or the other thing I keep thinking about, but not actually doing yet...)

Comment: So, what exactly would you recommend @torek? I've pretty clueless about what to do because I want to keep both frontend and backend together but it seems like I can't find a git setup to do that (as far as I know). Maybe there's some other way to deploy?

Comment: I don't use Heroku so I'm not sure what it demands. I personally hate submodules and try to avoid them, but it seems like they'd work here, *if* you redo your workflow. (The need to redo workflows, and the miserable way that submodules work—people call them *sob*-modules for a reason—is why I try to avoid them.) Anyway, I don't have any kind of final advice or solution here, just a note that submodules don't quite work the way you want. They *are* usable (in Git, not sure about Heroku), though.

Comment: Interesting. So one thing I've done is basically removed the `backend` repo (delete .git), and then verify that `my-app` begins to accept everything inside `backend` as if `backend` did not exist. From there, I `git init`'d inside the `backend` folder which has done the trick. Would you know why this is the case?

Comment: You've just set yourself up with a bad situation: your top level repository now has commits that contain files that overwrite files in your `backend` repository. You can now lose work you've been doing in the `backend` repository when you do work in your top level repository. Git depends (internally and rather heavily) on the idea that what's in the working tree goes along with what's in Git's index, and vice versa, and if you have overlapping repositories like this, that can't work. That's why Git wouldn't let you add submodule files earlier.

Comment: (You've just encountered one of the many reasons people call them sob-modules!)